# C# member method as static method ("reversed extension method")

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, function-pointers, extension-methods

Is it possible in C# to get a reference to a member function **without specifying the object**, so that it is usable like a static extension method, taking the object as first parameter?

```
class Handler
{
    public void Add(int value) { ... }
}

static class HandlerExtensions
{
    public static void AddEx(this Handler instance, int value) { ... }
}


var x = new Handler();

// possible:
Action<int> func1 = x.Add;
Action<Handler, int> func2 = HandlerExtensions.AddEx;

// not possible?
Action<Handler, int> func3 = Handler::Add;
```

Why would I want to do that? To specify methods to call in a class before having an actual object to work with:

```
// current solution:
void RegisterDto<DataType>(Func<Handler, Action<DataType>> handler) { ... }
RegisterDto<int>(x => x.Add);

// desired solution:
void RegisterDto<DataType>(Action<Handler, DataType> handler) { ... }
RegisterDto<int>(Handler::Add); // <--- does syntax for this exist?
```

Comment: My first confusion is that where youve put "// not possible?" you dont have a n `Add` method that matches that signature `Action<X,int>`. My second is what `X` is - your class is called `Handler` - shouldnt it be `var x = new Handler()`?

Comment: @Jamiec Sorry, X is Handler

Comment: thought so - but my first question.... ?

Comment: @Jamiec That would be a static method, I was thinking of a member method, but without specifying a concrete object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean "can you create a delegate like that" then the answer is "yes, but it's slightly ugly". I don't *think* you can use a method group conversion, but you can use reflection and `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, e.g.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Handler).GetMethod("Add");
var action = (Action<Handler, int>) 
    Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Handler, int>), method);
```

It would be nice to have a method group conversion here, I agree.

Comment: Thank you. It's ugly, but close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This might not work for you use-case, but you can create a delegate with

```
Action<Handler, int> f = (h, v) => h.Add(v);
```

And to use it

```
var handler = new Handler();
f(handler, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that you can do this. I'm already creating a delegate for "selecting" the corrent method to handle a given DataType, but it's evaluated each time the handler is invoked. I was thinking of directly specifying the method in the class, and use the concrete Handler-object (created in the future) to invoke it with a single call.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to evaluate it each time, maybe you could make it `Lazy`

```
        Func<Lazy<Handler>, Action<int>> addMethod = target =>  target.Value.Add;
        // example of usage
        var lazyHandler = new Lazy<Handler>();
        Test(addMethod(lazyHandler), 1);
```